# Changing Raster Layer Resampling with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

How can I set the zoomedInResampler of a Raster Layer to Cubic and the zoomedOutResampler to Average using PyQGIS?

Comment: Perhaps the API for the [QgsRasterResampleFilter Class](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterResampleFilter.html#ae48f74037899c5de0d48c2f681516949) might help :)

Comment: Been there, didn't help :) ...any examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, looking deeper into the API helped:

```
rasterLayer = iface.activeLayer()
resampleFilter = rasterLayer.resampleFilter()
resampleFilter.setZoomedInResampler(QgsCubicRasterResampler())
resampleFilter.setZoomedOutResampler(QgsBilinearRasterResampler())
```

Comment: Took me a while to figure out but if you would like to disable resampling (nearest neighbour) its:
resampleFilter.setZoomedOutResampler(None)