# How to resample QgsRasterLayer in QGIS 3?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-3, resampling

I am generating png images of concentration maps, resulting from air quality modelling. Resulting files are croped and coverted to tiff files and than loaded into QGIS in Python:

```
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(data_folder+parametr+'.tif',opis_txt)
projectInstance.addMapLayer(rlayer)
```

Then I load a pre-defiend QgsPrintoutLayout and export the results to a pdf file. Everything works fine, however by default raster is interpolated using Nearest Neighborhood which creates pixelized results.

In QGIS interface I can switch the resampling method for each layer to cubic or bilnear and this solves my problem, however I would like to do it automatically. So my question is can I do the same in Python script?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Changing Raster Layer Resampling with PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208877/changing-raster-layer-resampling-with-pyqgis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you Joseph. Your comment solves my problem.

```
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(data_folder+parametr+'.tif',opis_txt)
resampleFilter = rlayer.resampleFilter()
resampleFilter.setZoomedInResampler(QgsCubicRasterResampler())
resampleFilter.setZoomedOutResampler(QgsCubicRasterResampler())
projectInstance.addMapLayer(rlayer)
```

I was unable to find QgsCubicRasterResampler in the API doc, because I was searching for a clas name wich contains QgsRasterResampler